# Windows login screen not letting me enter PIN

Tags: windows, windows-10, boot, login, login-screen

When I boot up my windows 10 computer, the login screen opens with the time, date and the personalised background picture, as normal. I am able to move the cursor with my mouse, but when I want to go onto the screen where you enter your PIN (by pressing any key on the keyboard or left clicking anywhere), nothing happens. The cursor can move, but I can't go onto the PIN screen. The only way to make it work is by turning it off by the power button and turning it on again. This will lead me to the "Recovery" screen ("It looks like windows didn't load correctly"). Then, I will click the button that says "Continue: Exit and continue to windows 10". After this, the login screen will start normally, but this time with no personalised background and the default one of a cave in a beach. Now, it works as intended, with the ability to login to windows as normal. This happens every time I boot up the computer. The first time it happened, I tried sfc /scannow command. This found corrupted system files and fixed them. However, this still happens every time I boot up my computer. Now, sfc /scannow finds nothing wrong.

I have Windows 10 Home provided by the manufacturer (DELL Alienware)

My computer is the Alienware M17 R3

Multiple malware scanners/antivirus have found nothing wrong.

If needed, I can provide a list of installed programs/log files.

I would really appreciate an answer as to why its happening and a fix. Thank you.

Comment: Does entering the pin via the on-screen-keyboard or a USB keyboard work?

Comment: Go to Setup, Accounts, Sign in, and remake your PIN.  Be sure a Password exists before doing this.

Comment: @mashuptwice I think you misunderstood - I can't get onto the screen where I enter the PIN unless I restart. It's not that I can't type in the PIN.

Comment: What happens if you press CTRL+ALT+DEL?

Comment: Try the Setup process that I posted.

Comment: 1. Try DISM (in addition to SFC) to repair the image: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/repair-a-windows-image?view=windows-11 . 2. If that fails, try reinstalling Windows, keeping all files (i.e., repair, not replace). 3. If that fails, then  something is wrong with the user's profile. It might require recreating the user, transferring data, reinstalling software...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem with the DISM command as stated in DrMoishe Pippik's comment. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).